# React Grid Layout all directions resize

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

Has anyone fixed the issue with the `react-grid-layout`'s top and left side resize yet? I am poking around the library, trying to find a fix or to pass a function in order to resize it correctly, but no luck so far.